# refresh data read from text file with out page refresh

Tags: html, jscript

i am a novice at Java and JS so this will be very basic.

I've got this code that creates a text file in a specific directory. i only got as far as creating an actuale file, however, as the text file will be frequantely updated, i need the page to refresh/reload the text file and display it's data (just in the blank page). How do i do this, with out user needed to click refresh (auto refresh in  sense, however, i've tried auto refresh and it does not seem to reload JS and/or display text file's content)

### Create Text file/Read/Display content/Refresh and/or Reload - no user refresh

```
<script>
    function createFile()
    {   
        var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var file = object.CreateTextFile("C:/Documents and Settings/galimbek.sagidenov/My Documents/Practice HTML_Photoshop_java/BroadcastTest.txt", false);
        file.WriteLine('Hello World');
        file.WriteLine('Hope is a thing with feathers, that perches on the soul.'); 
    file.Close();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: first: your code uses ActiveXObject which is available only on IE not chrome,firefox,safari,etc..

seconde : this code will not work if your code hosted on server , becuase it is using local user files, and this may cause security issue if you can access users files -can you imagine!!-

Comment: how can i do it so it suits all browser types. And it does not matter if people can access the file - it is located on a closed network - no access from outside world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will not accomplished by using client side javascript only you have to use server side code:

server ex (using node.js):

server :

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs=require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
 fs.writeFileSync("C:/Documents and Settings/galimbek.sagidenov/My Documents/Practice HTML_Photoshop_java/BroadcastTest.txt", 'Hello World\r\nHope is a thing with feathers, that perches on the soul.');

}).listen(8888);
```

client

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8888",function(){
        console.log("writing to file successeded");
    })
})
</script>
```